# deleting a row from table

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to make a delete link, when i click on it it will delete a row from sql table with given ID, it should go like this, but it's not working, can you please take a look at my code and tell me what am I doing wrong, thanks !

This is what the link, when i click on archive it should delete the row.

```
echo '<td><a href="archivenews.php?newsid='. $row['ID'] .'">Arhiviraj</a>/<a href="archivenews.php?newsid='. $row['ID'] .'">Obrisi</a></td>';
```

and this is archivenews.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require('konektor.php');

    if(!(isset($_SESSION["login"]) && $_SESSION["login"] == "OK")) 
    {
        header("Location: index.php");
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        $id = $_GET['newsid'];
        $query = "DELETE FROM `Oglasi` WHERE `ID` = '$id'";
        header("Location: oglasi.php");
    }
?>
```

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: 1. You just declare a Variable with a sql query... But you never execute it ... And use prepared querys .. Read about sql injection

Comment: You are just defining a query here in the `$query` variable, you are not executing it, so nothing happens. And `please take a look into SQL-Injections, you are danger using this code`.

Comment: Thank you, I'm learning prepared statements at the moment :)

Comment: You are not executing a query in the above script you are only setting a variable $query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this before ' header("Location: oglasi.php"); ' -

```
mysql_query($query);
```

You need to perform the query against the database and mysql_query() does that.

So, your code becomes-

```
<?php
session_start();
require('konektor.php');

if(!(isset($_SESSION["login"]) && $_SESSION["login"] == "OK")) 
{
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
else
{
    $id = $_GET['newsid'];
    $query = "DELETE FROM `Oglasi` WHERE `ID` = '$id'";
    mysql_query($query);
    header("Location: oglasi.php");
}
?>
```

Just to check that the query has been executed right there, you can also do this-

```
    <?php
session_start();
require('konektor.php');

if(!(isset($_SESSION["login"]) && $_SESSION["login"] == "OK")) 
{
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit;
}
else
{
    $id = $_GET['newsid'];
    $query = "DELETE FROM `Oglasi` WHERE `ID` = '$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(!$result) 
    {
        die("Could not archive" . mysql_error());
        //This will display any error in the execution of query.
    } 
    header("Location: oglasi.php");
}
?>
```